# Bearer JWT session token value

Tags: authentication, python

I am working on a personal project, I am now working on the authentication. My back-end is written in Python (fast-API) and I am generating a JWT bearer token that I put on my cookies for my front end.

```
class OAuth2PasswordBearerWithCookie(OAuth2):
    def __init__(
        self,
        tokenUrl: str,
        scheme_name: Optional[str] = None,
        scopes: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = None,
        auto_error: bool = True,
    ):
        if not scopes:
            scopes = {}
        flows = OAuthFlowsModel(password={"tokenUrl": tokenUrl, "scopes": scopes})
        super().__init__(flows=flows, scheme_name=scheme_name, auto_error=auto_error)

    async def __call__(self, request: Request) -> Optional[str]:
        authorization: str = request.cookies.get("access_token")  #changed to accept access token from httpOnly Cookie
        print("access_token is",authorization)

        scheme, param = get_authorization_scheme_param(authorization)
        if not authorization or scheme.lower() != "bearer":
            if self.auto_error:
                raise HTTPException(
                    status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                    detail="Not authenticated",
                    headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
                )
            else:
                return None
        return param


oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearerWithCookie(tokenUrl="/api/v1/token")
```

It is working as expected, this jwt bearer token is actually visible on my front-end and when I modify it's value or delete it, I am not able to use my API anymore. However, I am wondering if the value of this token should contain the word "bearer", from what I found online it should only be a long string. Am I doing something wrong here?

[image]

Comment: It should not contain Bearer. Bearer is part of the authorization header followed by JWT. `{'authorization': 'Bearer eyJh...'}`.